# Cannot remove items from shopping cart (in the frontend) but works in the backend

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been building a shopping cart in Vanilla JS. I have an interface that deals with all the logic in the DOM, with a backend that deals with the manipulation of the array.

My problem is that I am having trouble with my button that attempts to remove an items from my cart. Not sure why my code doesn't remove items from the cart, but it definitely works with my tests!

I have tried to link the items in the cart to an id which increments as you had more to the cart (so each item in the cart has it's own unique id) and I've been trying to access these individually via an addEventLister('click'), then call my removeItem() method and then render the cart outside of the loop. It doesn't work unfortunately and I'm quite stuck. 
flow of data cart.js > interface > index.html

**cart.js**

```
class Cart {
  constructor() {
    this.cartArray = []
    this.total = 0
  }
  add(item) {
    this.cartArray.push(item)
  }
  removeItem(item) {
      var position = this.cartArray.lastIndexOf(item)
      this.cartArray.splice(position, 1)
  }

  calculateTotal() {
    var reducedTotal = this.cartArray.reduce( (previous, current) => {
      return this.total = previous + current.price
    },0)
    return reducedTotal
  }
}
```

**interface.js - deals with all DOM components**

```
function iniitalize () {
  var itemList = "<table border='1|1'>";
  var shoppingCartList = document.getElementById("shoppingCartList")
  var total = document.getElementById("total")

  var eachParagraph = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-item') 

  var cart = new Cart

  function showItems() {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        itemList +="<tr>";
        itemList += "<td>" +  items[i].name + "</td>"
        itemList += "<td>" + items[i].category + "</td>"
        itemList += "<td> " + items[i].price + "</td>"
        itemList += "<td> " + items[i].stock  + "</td>" 
        itemList += ` <td> <button id=${items[i].id}>add to cart</button> </td>`
        itemList +="</tr>";
    }
    itemList += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("itemsList").innerHTML = itemList;
  }

  function renderCart() {
    var print = "";
    var indexOfItem = 0
    cart.cartArray.forEach(function(element, index) {
      print +=  `<p id=${index}  class=${index}>` +  element.name + element.price 
      + `<button id=${indexOfItem}>Remove from cart</button> </p>`
      indexOfItem ++
    })
    return print
  }

  function renderTotal(){
    cart.calculateTotal()
    return "£" + cart.total
  }

  function removeItemButtonFunctionality() {
    cart.cartArray.forEach(function(element, index) {
      shoppingCartList.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cart.removeItem(element)
      })
    })
    renderCart()
  }


  function addToButtonFunctionality() {
    items.forEach( function(element, index) {
      document.getElementById(index).addEventListener('click', () => {
        cart.add(element)
        shoppingCartList.innerHTML = renderCart()
        total.innerHTML = renderTotal()
      })
    })
  }

  showItems()
  addToButtonFunctionality() 
  removeItemButtonFunctionality()
}


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iniitalize)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <h1>Shopping retailer</h1>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="itemsList"></div>
<br>

<h3>Total:</h3>
<div id="total">
</div> 

  <h3>Shopping Cart:</h3>

  <p id="shoppingCartList"></p>





  <script src="src/items.js"></script>
  <script src="src/cart.js"></script>
  <script src="./interface.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of issues with this code. First, you're probably repeating some ids on some elements. Every id needs to be unique, otherwise you won't be able to get elements using `getElementById`. It is common practice to prepend the value of the id with a keyword that means what exactly the element is.

Second, the remove button elements are not rendered yet when you run the `removeItemButtonFunctionality` at the end of the `initialize` function. Those event handlers need to be added dynamically as you add the items.

Third, it's not an issue, but I would probably change the code so that when `renderCart` is called, the cart is rendered, instead of returning a string and expecting that the other function will do that for you. For example, on the `removeItemButtonFunctionality` you're not doing anything when calling `rederCart()`.

The same would apply to the `renderTotal`.

So, in the end, I would change the code to be like this:

```
function renderCart() {
  shoppingCartList.innerHTML = '';
  cart.cartArray.forEach(function(element) {
    shoppingCartList.innerHTML += `<p id="cart${element.id}">${element.name} ${element.price}<button id="remove${element.id}">Remove from cart</button></p>`;
    var removeButton = document.getElementById('remove' + element.id);
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      cart.removeItem(element);
      renderCart();
      renderTotal();
    });
  })
}
```

and `renderTotal`:

```
function renderTotal(){
  total.innerHTML = "£" + cart.calculateTotal();
}
```

`addToButtonFunctionality` would only call the render functions:

```
function addToButtonFunctionality() {
  items.forEach( function(element, index) {
    document.getElementById(index).addEventListener('click', () => {
      cart.add(element)
      renderCart();
      renderTotal();
    })
  })
}
```

and at the end of the function you would only need to call:

```
showItems()
addToButtonFunctionality()
```

Comment: I added the changes, however I'm still having trouble with targeting each button, would I have to use the event.target to target each remove button?

Comment: Acutally, I didn't notice that you where not adding those handlers dynamically, I changed my answer to reflect the changes needed to do that

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It works, but only works when you click on the initial remove button of that particular item. For example, x = item1 and if you added "x" 3 times to the cart, you would have to click on the first item "x" in order to remove the third item "x". In addition, you can only remove items in the order you added them. For instance, x = item1, y = item2 and z = item 3 (you would have to remove "z" in order to remove "y". Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't think about that case. Well, thinking about a real cart application, I would probably want to show the numbers of repetitions of an item in a cart, instead of seeing three items. But if you wanted the three items to appear, you would need to change the way you get the button. The best way, is to instead of just appending text to the `shoppingCart.innerHTML`, you would create the elements using the DOM functions, modify them and then append them to the `shoppingCart` element.